# How do I use :checked on radio buttons

Tags: css, wordpress, radio-button, checked

How do I use the :checked css for my radio buttons with hidden input buttons?
http://cormilu.com.br/loja/sem-categoria/test-2/

I've tried:

```
input[type=”radio”]:checked{ color:red; … }
input[type="radio"]:checked+label{ color:red; …  } 
label > input + img{ color:red; … }
label > input:checked + img{color:red; … }
```

Is it because of my page setup? Ihid the input radio buttons and replaced them with images.

Thanks for your help.
Cheers,
Amir

Comment: Your selectors seems to be fine, but clearly `img{color:red;}` does not do anything, I wondered if you want to change the color of the text next to the image? - http://jsfiddle.net/8ebrycqx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you can't target the image or the label which you had replaced the radio button with.

You can either:

1) Use JavaScript to change things (targeting `parentNode`) upon radio button click/change

2) Change the HTML markup if it is able to solve your problem, and apply CSS:

Move the `<img>` tag after the `<input>` and use the CSS sibling selector (`+`):

**HTML:**

```
<label class="hideradio-vars">
    <input type="radio" value="20-bolas-fio-de-3m" id="pa_kit" name="attribute_pa_kit">
    <img src="http://cormilu.com.br/cormilu-content/uploads/2015/04/free1.png">
    &nbsp; &nbsp; 20 Bolas Fio de 3m
</label>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hideradio-vars input[type="radio"]:checked + img {
    /* Your rules here */
}
```

Unfortunately you cannot target the parent with CSS, so you might want to look into JS/jQuery or to revise your HTML markup entirely.

Comment: Hi Irvin, thanks for the heads up! Good to know that there's an underlying html issue. I changed the HTML order and now I'm able to mark the img with :checked. with this new setup how can I have the text change colors too? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You'll have to wrap the text in a <span>, then target them via `input:checked + img + span`, which starts to become quite ugly imo. But it works.